# How do I make a video clip "blink" in after effects

Tags: expression, after-effects

I am attempting something conceptually straight forward, but practically difficult to figure out. I want to make a video clip "blink" or "flicker" in after effects. I have two video clips layered on top of each other in after effects, and I want to make the top video, including it's audio, flicker on and off so that when the video is "off" the video playing beneath is visible.

Anyone familiar with after effects who can advise me on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like that inside opacity property:

```
speed = 5;
(value * Math.floor(Math.cos(time * Math.PI * speed) ) )
```